# WPF ContextMenu click routed to WinForms application

Tags: wpf, winforms, ms-word, vsto, contextmenu

I am writing a WPF control which is hosted in an Word VSTO AddIn (WinForms). Now I have a problem with the mouse click events on a context menu.

If I click on a context menu item on the left half (the part over the WinForms app), the click goes directly to the WinForms app and my context menu does not receive the event.

If I click the right half of the item (part over the WPF form), everything works as expected.

[image: Illustrated the issue]

Can someone out there help me solve this issue?

Comment: Interesting bug! Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some deep research I stumbled upon the following bug:

https://web.archive.org/web/20101211205036/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/VisualStudio/feedback/details/432998/excel-2007-vsto-custom-task-pane-with-wpf-context-menu-has-focus-problems

It's for Excel 2007, but is still valid for other Office products (2007, 2010). I managed to fix my issue using the method described here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20151231010333/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2009/12/16/excel-2007-wpf-events-are-not-fired-for-items-that-overlap-excel-ui-for-wpf-context-menus.aspx

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore, but still managed to get it with https://web.archive.org/ . I'll post the copy and pasted answer, just to save some time for anyone who might need this.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I updated the links to the archive version.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from the inactive blog is:

Declare a class level dispatcher frame object

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame _frame;
```

Subscribe to the GotFocusEvent and LostFocusEvent for the menu:

```
_menu.AddHandler(System.Windows.UIElement.GotFocusEvent,new RoutedEventHandler(OnGotFocusEvent));
_menu.AddHandler(System.Windows.UIElement.LostFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnLostFocusEvent));
```

Below is the implementation for the event procedures for the GotFocusEvent and LostFocusEvent:

```
private void OnGotFocusEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 if (LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource) == _menu)
  {
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal (DispatcherOperationCallback)delegate(object unused)
        {
         _frame = new DispatcherFrame();
         Dispatcher.PushFrame(_frame);
         return null;
        }, null);
  }
}

private void OnLostFocusEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource) == _menu)
  {
     _frame.Continue = false;
  }
}
```

In my case, the if statements weren't needed and I subscribed to the events like this

```
<EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="contextMenu_GotFocus" />
<EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="contextMenu_LostFocus" />
```